# How to download android app using .apk link directly from phone?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web

I have a list of .apk files on a webpage which I want to be able to download directly from my phone. So I should be able to navigate to that webpage and click the .apk link and it should download the app on my phone. Basically right now my web page is listing these apk files but if I try to click on one of the links using an android emulator, nothing happens. Any advice on how I can make these .apk links downloadable directly from the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator might not support downloads. I would try it with your phone, or if your webpage is not yet available find one that does have .apk and try it.

Comment: So, just clicking the link should work on a phone? I don't have a phone right now to check.

Comment: It definitely works - and you should get yourself a real phone if you plan to program Android in earnest.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator doesn't have any program to install apps like that. Here's what you can do though: 
Download the app onto your computer and use adb to install it on your emulator, like so:

1. Download the apk to your computer to SOME_FOLDER
2. Add the platform-tools folder in your Android-SDK to your PATH. (this is the folder in your Android-SDK that has adb.exe)
3. Open up a command prompt and navigate to SOME_FOLDER.
4. Type "adb devices -l" and you should be able to see your emulator listed in the devices (your emulator already running, right?)
5. Now, type "adb install YOUR_APK_NAME.apk"

That's it. The last command might take upto a minute, or more. When its done you should see your app installed in the emulator. 
For more details on using adb, please see here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary